# How can I draw waveform in UWP application?

Tags: c#, uwp, waveform

I have a UWP app that want to display the whole  waveform from mp3 or mp4 etc. I tried to use NAudio.WaveFormRenderer(https://github.com/naudio/NAudio.WaveFormRenderer), but it doesn’t use in UWP app due to .Net.Core is strict about reading files.

I want to know how to draw whole waveform from read mp3, mp4.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging

Comment: @jdweng I think your comment cannot solve my problem. I want to know how to draw whole waveform from read mp3, mp4.

Comment: One way is I think you could contact with the author of the NAudio to see if they can provide you an UWP NAudio libiary. Another way is you render the waveform yourself, but I think it's complex, it involves many APIs, not sure if they are available in UWP.